# How to preload variables in ./manage.py shell in Django 3.0.3+?

Tags: python, django

I do most of my work through the shell in django. I'd like to preload imports and variables so as to keep myself from having to type 
`from app.models import *`

Comment: You might want to look into Jupyter/IPython.

Comment: If you have IPython installed you can start your django shell like so: `./manage.py shell_plus --notebook` See https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html

Comment: You can edit the `manage.py` file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. Here's a few of them.

The `shell_plus` command from [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shell_plus.html) will automatically import your models on startup.

Django's shell will use the [`PYTHONSTARTUP` script](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonstartup#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) if you have one defined, same as the plain Python shell would. (Assuming you're using the default shell.) This is run in the same namespace as the Django shell, so if you do your imports there, they will show up in the Django shell.

IDEs that support a Django shell will allow you to define a startup script to use when the integrated Django shell is started. Check the settings. (PyCharm Pro, for example, can do this.)

Comment: Thank you. I'm a default guy. I'll go with Pythonstartup script.